# Retrieve JSON data as String

Tags: json, reactjs, postgresql, draftjs

I use Draft.js as editor in my website. I can save the editor text as json format in the Database.But i want to save json data as string/Html, but it's comes out in json format. Here is what i have done so far for saving the value as json format:

```
<Editor
    blockStyleFn={getBlockStyle}
    customStyleMap={styleMap}
    editorState={this.state.editorState}
    handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    placeholder="Describe the requirements and skills needed for the job"
    ref="editor"
    spellCheck={true}
/>
<h4>Editor content as HTML</h4>
<pre>{this.state.editorContentHtml}</pre>
```

And this the function for showing the html code under editor:

```
this.onChange = editorState => {
        this.setState({
            editorState,
            editorContentHtml: stateToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent())

        });

    };
```

This is the snapshot of my editor

[image]
this is the result after retrieving editor data

[image: this is the result after retrieving editor data]

I want to save the html result in database and also show it as html. Any help regarding this would be appreciated or if there is any other alternative way for retrieving data as String format.

Comment: Whats the problem? What happens when you try and store the HTML in your database?

Comment: JSON *is* a string. It's a string with a specific format. Are you asking how to retrieve the rendered HTML?

Comment: @JoshPittman  I want to save the HTML but its Saving as a JSON format

Comment: draft has a plugin that converts them. just use that.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/draftjs-to-html

Comment: @jobaersourav draft doesn't return the HTML text for very good security reasons - think XSS and script injection attacks. You need a separate plugin to render its contents into HTML, assuming you *really* need to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render html saved from draft-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174692/render-html-saved-from-draft-js)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Its saving as a JSON format and i want retrieve it as a HTML.

Comment: @jobaersourav the duplicate explains that you can't do that with draft itself, why you shouldn't, and what plugins can be used like `draftjs-to-html`. There are other duplicates too, but all contain the same answers

Comment: @jobaersourav [this possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224446/draft-js-saving-and-displaying-html) points to [draft-js-export-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-export-html), a very popular plugin

Comment: I want to save the data as a HTML and retrieve it in the same format or  save it as JSON and retrieve it as a HTML.Can  i do it either way?

Comment: I already did the part draftjs-to-html .But I can't save the html in database